# Grails: Is it possible to query PostgreSQL server version?

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

In a Grails 1.3.9 application that I need to maintain there is a query using **like**. Customer installations can use different PostgreSQL database versions (7.3 and 9.x).

The search pattern can in general contain non-ASCII characters. Such **SELECT .. WHERE columns LIKE pattern** statements don't work properly with PostgreSQL 7.x and have to be handled in a different way.

Is there a way in Grails to determine the PostgreSQL server version in runtime to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can issue raw SQL:

```
select version();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will incorporate this query in Grails.